# Delete Trigger with Update Subquery Statement with Multirow Delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

This trigger is working fine with single row delete, but on multiple row

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[AfterDeleteStockUpdate] 
ON [dbo].[ItemLedger]
AFTER DELETE
AS 
    DECLARE @productId uniqueidentifier

    SELECT @productId = del.Product 
    FROM deleted del;

    UPDATE products 
    SET inStock = (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(inQty, 0)) - SUM(ISNULL(outQty, 0)) 
                   FROM itemledger 
                   WHERE product = @productId), 
        PurchasedValue = (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(PurchaseAmount, 0)) - SUM(ISNULL(Amount, 0)) 
                          FROM itemledger 
                          WHERE product = @productId) 
    WHERE id = @productId
```

Comment: You have an answer that appears to cure your primary problem. But it followed the pattern you attempted which is HIGHLY inefficient. Why is it inefficient? Because you sum all the related existing rows in the ledger table - and there is absolutely no reason to do that. What you should be doing is using the deleted table to simply update the affected products. And your usage of ISNULL is incorrect and likely is not needed if we assume a proper foreign key exists.

Comment: Perhaps a materialized view might be a better solution? That will automatically adjust for changes in the ledger without any trigger code.

Answer (score 2):

The `Deleted` pseudo-table can have 0-N rows in it, which you need to handle. And like all T-SQL you want to be using a fully set-based approach wherever possible anyway as thats what SQL Server is optimised for.

I believe the following should accomplish what you are wanting.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[AfterDeleteStockUpdate] 
ON [dbo].[ItemLedger]
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE P SET
      inStock = L.inStock
      , PurchasedValue = L.PurchasedValue
    FROM Products P
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT SUM(ISNULL(L.inQty, 0)) - SUM(ISNULL(L.outQty, 0)) inStock
            , SUM(ISNULL(L.PurchaseAmount, 0)) - SUM(ISNULL(L.Amount, 0)) PruchasedValue
        FROM itemledger L
        GROUP BY L.product
    ) L ON L.product = P.id
    WHERE P.id IN (SELECT Product from Deleted);

END;
```

Comment: @hsn did this answer your question?

Comment: I have used fetch/cursor to solve my problem, i will try this approach and will update you accordingly

Comment: @hsn - you certainly want to avoid cursors in triggers if at all possible,